# Places Api and google maps showing different school results for same location

Tags: javascript, maps, google-places-api

I am trying to use Google Places API to find schools nearby to the given postcode. The lat/long that I am using in my API call are the same that are returned by Google Maps website, however the list of schools is almost 80% different.

My API call looks like below

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.515176,-0.148573&type=school&key=API_KEY&radius=4829

What can I do to get more accurate results back from Google Places API, ideally the same list as returned from maps.google.com?